# add music to my iPhone with out losing the existing once

Tags: itunes, music, sync, local

prove me if I am wrong, I am fan of apple products, but the iTune application which is supposedly the heart of many of the transactions looks so messy for me specially with music. I have more than 5 computers it is always painful for me to add new music to my phone with out losing what I have already, in addition to that every time I open iTunes they just keep on asking me to update. What the hell is that, shouldn't this to happen at list once in two month?

any ways my main question is that, I bought some music from iTunes but cant I add my other music also with out losing what I bought from itune, and what I have already on my phone from other source?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're synchronizing your device with more than one computer.

Don't do that.

You need to designate one computer as your "master" and sync your device(s) only on that machine. This machine should also be where you keep the master copy of all your music and other media.

You can get new music files from anywhere, but if you don't buy it in iTunes on the master machine or on the device itself, you will need to copy it to the master computer and add it to iTunes if you want it sync'ed on your device.

Make sure that iTunes is set to NOT AUTOMATICALLY SYNC devices on all other computers.

You can still access your media files from other computers, but they should do that across the network if possible. If you need to download local copies to a laptop or other machine where you can't access the main machine on the network, just remember that if you get anything new on that machine, you're going to need to copy it over later to the master machine and add it to iTunes there.

Comment: thanks Mike, but it looks they have a bit unpractical approach. I don't see the logic behind for doing all this, we can eventually upload un-purchacsaded music to our un cracked phone. like I bought one music CD form store and I want to upload it to my phone, it should be straight forward.

Comment: There are other ways to put music on your iPhone. It's just a bit complicated if you use iTunes to do it, because iTunes only does "sync" instead of just "upload".